# how to Embed Youtube Video with Autoplay, Looping, and show controls?

Tags: youtube, embed

how to Embed Youtube Video with Autoplay, Looping, and show controls?

Hi How do I make the video work continuously without interruption while at the same time showing control

Comment: I want to make the video work continuously but show control.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is to modify url parameter for example autoplay=1 loop=1 and control=1

https://www.youtube.com/embed/E5ln4uR4TwQ?**autoplay**=1&**loop**=1&**playlist**=E5ln4uR4TwQ"

Please refer [YouTube Embedded Players and Player Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) for more settings.

** we need **playlist** parameter to make looping work, while the value will be your video id

> Note: This parameter has limited support in the AS3 player and in IFrame embeds, which could load either the AS3 or HTML5 player. Currently, the loop parameter only works in the AS3 player when used in conjunction with the playlist parameter. To loop a single video, set the **loop parameter value to 1** and set the **playlist parameter value to the same video ID** already specified in the **Player API URL:**

Comment: do not work !!
The video stops after it finishes and does not work again

Comment: I want to make the video work continuously but show control.

Comment: I found that the autohide of control bar is default design for flash player. In other words, there is no way to control the autohide of control bar in embedded youtube player